# error: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working with Cloud Vision API in java using IntelliJ to detect labels in camera pictures. The API is working fine, but when I add the android.graphics dependency to my maven pom.xml to use Bitmap ADT, it stops to work and throws an error: "No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact". I tried to add the dependencies below to my pom.xml, but nothing has changed. can someone please tell me what this error means?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

here is my code:

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Bitmap bmp;
    String description = "";
    // Instantiates a client
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {

        // The path to the image file to annotate
        String fileName = "c:/stairsPic.png";

        // Reads the image file into memory
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

        // Builds the image annotation request
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                .addFeatures(feat)
                .setImage(img)
                .build();
        requests.add(request);

       // Performs label detection on the image file
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }

            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
                description = annotation.getDescription();
                break;
            }
        }
        //finding the time difference and converting it into seconds
        float sec = (end - start) / 1000F;
        System.out.println(sec + " seconds");

        System.out.println("The photo description is: " + description);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I received the error that was described above just from doing the "import android.graphics.Bitmap" and declaring the Bitmap variable.
My actual result is to get Bitmap in my function signature and to send it to the cloud vision API without getting this error.

Comment: Is it possible to attach sample project for investigation?

Comment: I have added my code as a sample. Although the problem is only because of the import that I wrote and the Bitmap variable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it turned out as IntelliJ error.

First of all you need to check if you have your `grpc-netty-shaded` library under External libraries in your IDE. That was missing in my case. I had to remove all the libraries manually, run `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...` and than run `mvn compile` again.

After completing those steps you should see `grpc-netty-shaded` library in your external libraries.